# BigQuery cost for complex logic in custom functions

Tags: google-bigquery, cost-management

I am using relatively expensive computation in the custom function defined like this:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HMAC256(message STRING, secret STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js
  OPTIONS (
    -- copy this Forge library file to Storage:
    -- https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/node-forge@0.7.0/dist/forge.min.js
    -- @see https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge
    library=["gs://.../forge.min.js"]
  )
  AS
"""
  var hmac = forge.hmac.create();
  hmac.start('sha256', secret);
  hmac.update(message);
  return hmac.digest().toHex();
""";


SELECT HMAC256("test", "111");

-- Row  f0_
-- 1    f8320c4eded4b06e99c1a884a25c80b2c88860e13b64df1eb6f0d3191023482b
```

Will this be more expensive compared to applying `LOWER` function for example?

I cannot see anything different in the bytes billed details while `HMAC256` took 4 min on my dataset compared to 14 seconds for `LOWER`.

It would be awesome if price is the same. I have a feeling I miss something.

Comment: Congrats on having js HMAC running. Does it match R's SHA256() function?

Comment: Yes it does match my R/python hmac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The cost will be the same. Your query can get more complicated and more expensive to BigQuery, but you're only charged of same rate until your query hit the limit. Your off-limits query will fail if you don't have reservation (aka [flat-rate slots](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-manage-bigquery-flat-rate-slots-within-a-project)).

> All high compute queries under tier 100 are billed as tier 1.
>
> All queries above tier 100 will fail with a RESOURCES_EXCEEDED_PER_BYTE error unless the query is running in a reserved instance.

Comment: can you please clarify what exactly is "in a reserved instance"? Is this same as Flat-Price reservation or something else? the only reference I saw is [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#November_14_2017) - but it is not fully clear

Comment: Yes. It is [Flat-rate reservation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/how-to-manage-bigquery-flat-rate-slots-within-a-project).